# Create a list from a character vector fed to a function

Tags: r, function, arguments

I would like to pass variables into a function and use them as a list, and I have a function that splits the items of a character vector by the "=", and places them into a list. It works fine of course when the equal sign is included in the character like this:

```
my.function <- function(x) {
  args <- x
  newl <- list()

 for ( i in 1:length(args) ) {
   keyval <- strsplit(args[[i]],"=")[[1]];
   key <- keyval[1]; val <- keyval[2];
   newl[[ key ]] <- val;
 }
 return(newl)
}

char<- c("name=value_1", "title=title", "show=show")

my.function(char)

$name
[1] "value_1"

$title
[1] "title"

$show
[1] "show"
```

And then I am able to use these arguments inside the function just by doing this:

```
args[['title']]
```

But I would like to pass variables to the function, and not just characters. So I would like the function to be able to work when I do this:

```
value_1 = "A"
show= TRUE
title= paste("This is my title for ", value_1, sep="")

my.function(name=value_1, title=title, show=show)
```

I could just paste the values like this:

```
char= c( paste("name=", value_1, sep=""), 
         paste("title=", title, sep=""), 
         paste("show=", show, sep=""))
```

But I was wondering if there was a better method to pass these variables as arguments to the function. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `...`:

```
my.function <- function(...) list(...)
```

This function just creates a list based on the ussed arguments.

```
value_1 <- "A"
show <- TRUE
title <- paste("This is my title for ", value_1, sep="")


my.function(name = value_1, title = title, show = show)
$name
[1] "A"

$title
[1] "This is my title for A"

$show
[1] TRUE
```

---

This function generates a character vector based on the function call's arguments:

```
my.function <- function(...) {
  argList <- list(...)
  res <- paste(names(argList), unlist(argList), sep = "=")
  return(res)     
}

my.function(name=value_1, title=title, show=show)
[1] "name=A"                       "title=This is my title for A" "show=TRUE"
```

---

This function is similar to your one. It illustrates how you can access the arguments of the function call:

```
my.function <- function(...) {
  argList <- list(...)
  newl <- list()
  for (i in seq_along(argList)) {
    key <- names(argList)[i]
    val <- argList[[i]]
    newl[[key]] <- val
  }
  return(newl)    
}

my.function(name = value_1, title = title, show = show)
$name
[1] "A"

$title
[1] "This is my title for A"

$show
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you Sven… If I would like to use it on the function I have, it tells me it can't find x if I adjust my function like this:                  my.function <- function(...) {
  args <- x;
  newl <- list();

for ( i in 1:length(args) ) {
    keyval <- strsplit(args[[i]],"=")[[1]];
    key <- keyval[1]; val <- keyval[2];
    newl[[ key ]] <- val;
  }
  return(newl)
 }

Comment: @user2337032 What is your final goal? What do you want the function to return?

Comment: I would like to be able to give variables as arguments to the same function I have (although it seems like it is simple and just converts to list I made it simpler for the post…)

Comment: @user2337032 So, all you want is to return a list of strings?

Comment: @user2337032 See the update. It illustrates how you can access the function arguments.

Comment: sorry if this wasn't clear, there are many other functions that I am applying to the arguments specified (for example toupper and other checks), so I was hoping there was a way to get a character vector like this: c("name=A", "title=This is my title for A", "show=TRUE"), is this possible?